# MySQL update trigger works but SELECT query does not see new data

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2, koa

I have a MYSQL trigger that updates a table based upon the insert on another table. The updates are working correctly and I can see them from MYSQL workbench. However when performing the identical query from a koa/mysql2 javascript-based web server  only ***old*** data shows up, not the new updated records.   I am using MYSQL 5.7.17 (InnoDB) with a   mysql2 Node NPM package ( 1.1.2 ) and KOA 1.2.4.
The queries are really simple:

```
SELECT * FROM  db.tbl_update order by id DESC  LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Here is my.ini

```
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
port=3306

character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="DESKTOP-NA514FK.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="DESKTOP-NA514FK-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-bin="DESKTOP-NA514FK-bin"
log-error="DESKTOP-NA514FK.err"
server-id=1
secure-file-priv= 
max_connections=151
query_cache_size=0
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=98M
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=186M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=17
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=4M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4161
query_cache_type=0
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
plugin_load="mysqlx"
loose_mysqlx_port=33060
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked your mysql logs (adjusting the amount of log output as necessary)?

Comment: Yes I did check the errors log and there was no activity related to the query. Is there another log I should be checking?